# What does this line mean in subset sum problem's pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm trying to understand the [approximate polynomial time algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm) for subset sum problem at Wikipedia, but I stuck at the pseudocode's 3rd line:

> let T be a list consisting of x<sub>i</sub> + y, for all y in S

What does this line mean? What is `x`, and how do I create the correct `T` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the previous section:

> The problem can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time using dynamic programming. Suppose the sequence is
>   x[1], ..., x[N]
>   and we wish to determine if there is a nonempty subset which sums to zero.

So, it appears that x is the input sequences of numbers, for which you're trying to solve, and thus x[i] is the i'th number in the sequence.

Thus, the list T is a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) of S where each element of T is that of S but with x[i] added to it.